# How to show browser login form for basic authentication using RESTEasy

Tags: java, jax-rs, basic-authentication, resteasy

I´m currently messing around with JAX-RS specifically Resteasy, because it "just works" with Wildfly and I don´t have to configure anything. That´s really the only reason I use that.

I did already implement Basic Authentication, looking forward to replacing it with OAuth2 later, just did this now for simplicity reasons.

The ContainerRequestFilter looks like this

```
    @Provider
    public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX = "Basic ";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {

        if(isAuthenticated(containerRequestContext) == false)
            containerRequestContext.abortWith(createUnauthorizedResponse("Access denied."));
    }

    private boolean isAuthenticated(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
        List<String> authHeader = containerRequestContext.getHeaders().get(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY);

        ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker) containerRequestContext.getProperty("org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker");
        Method method = methodInvoker.getMethod();
        RolesAllowed rolesAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.size() > 0) {
            String authToken = authHeader.get(0).replaceFirst(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX, "");

            byte[] decoded = null;

            try {
                decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(authToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                return false;
            }

            String decodedString = new String(decoded);
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(decodedString, ":");

            String username = null, password = null;

            if(tokenizer.countTokens() < 2)
                return false;

            username = tokenizer.nextToken();
            password = tokenizer.nextToken();

            if (DbController.isValid(username, password, rolesAnnotation.value()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private Response createUnauthorizedResponse(String msg) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .entity("{ \"Unauthorized\" : \"" + msg + "\" }")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build();
    }
}
```

It works fine with postman. And I do realize that the main usage of such apis is in well other programs.

But it would be nice, if opened in a browser it would ask you to enter your credentials, instead of just telling you that you are not authorized, with no way to really enter your credentials. Unless you do some trickery to manually put it in the header, but then you might as well just use postman.

If I put a security constraint with auth-constraint role admin it does give a login dialog, but then the authorization does not work and it just keeps asking for authorization.

Is there anything else that I can do instead of containerRequestContext.abortWith? Or do I need to use a completely different approach and it just won´t work with ContainerRequestFilter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header to the response that you abort with. This header tells the browser that it should present the default browser login form.

```
private static final String CHALLENGE_FORMAT = "%s realm=\"%s\"";

private Response createUnauthorizedResponse() {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .header(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, String.format(CHALLENGE_FORMAT, "Basic", "Access"))
            .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .entity("Credentials are required to access this resource.")
            .build();
```

And here's what the login should look like on Chrome

[image]